# Using javascript to fill in an online form and getting the data to show up

Tags: javascript, forms, post, submit

I'm trying to fill in a form by pasting javascript into the debug console but although the data shows up on screen, the form still gives errors about being empty.

Is there a way to update an online form with javascript per element? I've seen people do it with a submit:

```
document.getElementById("firstName").value="Username";
document.forms[0].submit()
```

But I need the page to update after certain items because it will offer different fields in response. Also, I don't think there is an HTML form in the code because I get this response:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("firstName").form.id)
<empty string>
```

Could I do something (functionally) like this:

```
document.getElementById('firstName').value = 'myname';
document.getElementById('firstName').submit();
```

(I know this is not valid code, but I no idea how else to explain myself:(  )
One of the problems is that just setting the name makes it show up on screen, but when I press the pay button on the page it simply says the name is still not filled in. I then have to click the name field, type a space, press return, and then the name is finally 'seen', but with an extra space.

Answer (score 0):

if the `firstName` input is just a child element of the form, you can try

```
console.log(document.getElementById("firstName").parentNode.id);
document.getElementById('firstName').value = 'myname';
document.getElementById('firstName').parentNode.submit();
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! Is it possible that there is no form? And if so, is there still something I can do? I tried the following and got no data: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).parentNode.submit is not a function

Comment: Can you post the full code snippet, so that I can try to find the right element?